# Subset in R: extract logical factor from multiple columns

Tags: r, subset

I would like to known, how to subset in R based on condition. I have a large object with 10 columns, the 8 columns are logical. I want to extract all values TRUE for any 4 columns out of total 8 ?

Comment: Get the rowindex with `rowSums` i.e. `rowSums(df1[1:8]) >=4`.  assuming first 8 are logical columns

Answer (score 0):

See below. I create a vector that includes the names of the true/false variables. R will interpret TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0; consequently, when summing across rows we want to keep rows that have a sum of 4 or greater. `rowSums(df[,tf_vars]) >= 4` creates a TRUE/FALSE vector that indicates where the row has 4 or more trues. (Note that `df[,tf_vars]` will subset the columns of the dataframe, only keeping the variables in `tf_vars`). I then use that vector to subset the dataframe.

```
# Create dummy dataframe
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=100, ncol=0))
for(i in 1:8){
  df[[paste0("TFvar",i)]] <- sample(100, x=c(T,F), prob=c(.5,.5), replace=T)
}

# Subset dataframe where at least 4 of the columns are true
tf_vars <- c("TFvar1", "TFvar2", "TFvar3", "TFvar4", "TFvar5", "TFvar6", "TFvar7", "TFvar8")

  # (or you could use this to grab the variable names that are TRUE/FALSE variables.)
  tf_vars <- names(apply(df, FUN=is.logical, 2))


df_subset <- df[rowSums(df[,tf_vars]) >= 4,]
```

Comment: Hi Rob thanks. In total i have 80 columns and 600K rows, your command seems working but it does out put other rows as NA, which i do not want i want row only TRUE for atleast 4 columns